# Bind dropdownlist with integers

Tags: c#, binding, drop-down-menu

I have an int variable, e.g.

```
int i = 100;
```

What I want to do is binding a ddl with 100 listitems, from 1 to 100.
I could cycle the variable and for each number adding a ListItem to the ddl, but I'd like to know if there's an alternative, something like value the DataSource with the variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
int startingItem = 1;
int numberOfItems = 100;
IEnumerable<int> bindingSource = Enumerable.Range(startingItem, numberOfItems);
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know about this method +1

Answer (score 0):

If the text and value of each ListItem should be the same just use:

```
myDropDownList.DataSource = myListOfInts;
myDropDownList.DataBind();
```

Alternatively, you can use Linq for a more complex setup

```
myDropDownList.DataSource =
    from i in myListOfInts
    select new ListItem("My Num: " + i, i.ToString());
myDropDownList.DataBind();
```